# Update row only where max date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following data

```
Date                    Week    ID      Tot_Seconds   O_Seconds   Week_ID
8/14/2011 12:00:00 AM   5823    22180   170043        26043         18
8/21/2011 12:00:00 AM   5824    22180   126471           0          18
```

I am trying to update a column in another table the value of O_Seconds,where the week and ID match, but i would only like to update where max(date) for each Week. The reason, is the table with the data source has dates by week, where the the table I will update is daily, and using the query I currently have, it updates for example 26043 for all days where id and week match, skewing my future queries where I will sum the values of those columns.

Is there any way to just update the max date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

The derived table is used to get the 1st row per week/ID

```
UPDATE
   O
SET
   SomeCol = S.O_Second
FROM
   OtherTable O
   JOIN
   (
   SELECT
      Week, ID, O_Second, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Week, ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
   FROM
      ThisTable
   ) S ON O.Week = S.Week AND O.ID = S.ID
WHERE
   S.rn = 1
```

For SQL Server 2000 and earlier you need an aggregate. See [DBA.SE for more](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row/1004#1004)

Comment: This is giving me the same result as my query, which is that it's updating all the days, and not just the max.

Comment: @JP: run the derived table separately, you'll see rn = 1 for the max date per week/ID. That is, it will only extract the row where O_Second = 26043. Now, for that to update all rows in "OtherTable" means that Week/ID *isn't enough* to identify a row. This *does* work based on what you've given us. Add more data and table structures please